# How to convert a list into a string?

Tags: c#, selenium

I have a list displaying passenger titles:

```
public List<string> GetPassengerNames()
{
    List<string> titleList = new List<string>();

    var passengerTitles =  _driver.FindElements(PassengerDetailsElements.TitleField);

    foreach (var passengerTitle in passengerTitles)
    {
        SelectElement passengerTitleSelected = new SelectElement(passengerTitle);
        string passengerTitleText = passengerTitleSelected.SelectedOption.Text;
        titleList.Add(passengerTitleText);

    }

    return titleList;
}
```

I then add this into a scenario context:

```
[When(@"all passenger details are captured")]
public void WhenAllPassengerDetailsAreCaptured()
{
    var passengersList = _passengerDetails.GetPassengerNames();
    ScenarioContext.Current.Add("PassengersList", passengersList);
}
```

What I want to do is grab the text for each passenger when I grab this context but I am not sure how to do this for a list element.

I tried the below:

```
string passengersList = ScenarioContext.Current["PassengersList"].ToString().Select(c => c.Text()).ToArray();
```

What should the above code be in order to grab the text of each value from the list and store in an array?

Comment: Have you tried `string[] passengersList = ((List<string>)ScenarioContext.Current["PassengersList"]).ToArray();`? Why do you name a variable List, define it as a string and tell us you want an array???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use string join. I haven't checked this in visual studio, but it should work.

```
var passengersList = string.Join(", ", _passengerDetails.GetPassengerNames());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
var resultString = string.Join(",", passengersList);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code that you are using to add the list to the session is correct, if you want to retrieve the same from session means you have to use the following lines, instead for saving as a concatenated string, retrieving them and split to get the values. try this:

```
var passengerList = (List<string>)ScenarioContext.Current["PassengersList"];
// If you want them as a comma separated values then
string csvPassengerList = String.Join(",",passengerList);
```

Please note: [[Reference]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx)

> Session variables can be any valid .NET Framework type. The value
>   returned by session variable must be cast to the appropriate type when
>   you retrieve it from the SessionStateItemCollection.